# Some confusion with regard to setState callback in React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What is the fundamental difference between the code snippets down below?

```
function App(){
   let[value,setValue] = useState(0);

   let textClick=()=>{
       setValue(value+1)
       console.log(value)
   }

   return(
     <div className="App">
       <div onClick={textClick}>Click Me</div>
     </div>
);
}
```

and this

```
function App(){
   let[value,setValue] = useState(0);

   let textClick=()=>{
       setValue((i)=>i+1)
       console.log(value)
   }

   return(
     <div className="App">
       <div onClick={textClick}>Click Me</div>
     </div>
);
}
```

Are they the same? I am very confused with (the 2nd snippet) having another callback in setState given setState it self is already asynchronous.
Help needed.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should check the official docs, what says this: (Component and functional way should be fundamentally the same)

State Updates May Be Asynchronous
React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.

Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

For example, this code may fail to update the counter:

```
// Wrong
this.setState({
  counter: this.state.counter + this.props.increment,
});
```

To fix it, use a second form of setState() that accepts a function rather than an object. That function will receive the previous state as the first argument, and the props at the time the update is applied as the second argument:

```
// Correct
this.setState((state, props) => ({
  counter: state.counter + props.increment
}));
```

Source: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html